# Can 'argparse' consume a string instead of python script arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string and I need to extract the positional params and optional params from it.

"start command test --param_1 a --param_2 b"

Is there a way we can extract the params from a string instead of script arguments using 'argparse' module?

Thanks

Comment: https://pymotw.com/2/getopt/ this a good alternative?

Comment: That is not a job for argparse (or for getopt). argparse handles the stuff that comes *after* the step you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

[`argparse.parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) can accept a list to parse.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# Insert your rules

# Parse my string, first splitting it into a list.
args = parser.parse_args("start command test --param_1 a --param_2 b".split())
```

If you need to be careful about quotes in your string, [`shelx.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) may be better than `.split()`.